# Done button is not dismissing modalviewcontroller

Tags: iphone, modalviewcontroller, dismiss

When i click on the done button it is not dismissing modalviewcontroller in my case it is infoviewcontroller. Am i supposed to add something in mainviewcontroller h and m file.

In the Infoviewcontroller.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol ModalViewDelegate <NSObject>

-(void) dismissModalView;

@end

@interface Infoviewcontroller : UIViewController <UITextViewDelegate>

{
id<ModalViewDelegate>dismissDelegate;
UITextView *textView;
UINavigationBar *navBar;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextView *textView;
@property (nonatomic, assign) UINavigationBar *navBar;
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<ModalViewDelegate>dismissDelegate;

@end
```

In the Infoviewcontroller.m

```
#import "Infoviewcontroller.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>


@implementation Infoviewcontroller

@synthesize textView;
@synthesize navBar;
@synthesize dismissDelegate;



-(void)dealloc
{
[textView release];
[navBar release];
[super dealloc];
}

- (void) viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

    UIButton* backButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:101]; 
    [backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(dismissView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [backButton setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    // create button item
    UIBarButtonItem* backItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton];

    // add the button to navigation bar
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backItem;
    [backItem release];

 -(void)dismissView:(id)sender
{
    //Make the delegate close the modal
    [self.dismissDelegate dismissModalView];

}
```

When i click on the done button it is not dismissing modalviewcontroller in my case it is infoviewcontroller. Am i supposed to add something in mainviewcontroller h and m file. Please help me if i am missing some thing in the mainviewcontroller files.

Thanks for help,

Comment: Where do you set your 'dismissDelegate'?

Comment: -(void)dismissView:(id)sender
    {
    //Make the delegate close the modal
    [dismissDelegate dismissModalView];} in the infoviewcontroller.m in the end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
-(void)dismissView:(id)sender
{
       [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

but if you want to dismiss the controller in the delegate method then you first have to set the delegate in infoviewController then in the delegate method use the infoviewController object to dismiss it .

Comment: not exactly clear with your statement. can you please show me the steps. Thanks for help.

Comment: Just before you call `[self presentModalViewController:nextVC animated:YES]`; in the presenting view controller, add `nextVC.dismissDelegate = self;`. Obviously replace 'nextVC' with whatever name your using.

Comment: it is giving message that property dismissDelegate not found on object  of type UIViewController.